# WPF Leak when adding multiple items to a canvas and rendering using RenderBitmapTarget

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I've been having a whale of a time diagnosing a leak in a service which is rendering multiple images to a canvas and then pushing out a bitmap or PNG at the end (and doing this multiple times). On start up the service will rocket up to 600MB+ and then keep on increasing until it's taken almost all that it can get hold of. It will never decrease once started.

I've instrumented and run the service using the VS2012 perf mon and seen that there are large amounts of Byte arrays laying about after processing has been completed. I've tried a GC clear to see if it would wipe them out to no avail. Looking into it using WinDbg I can see that the byte array is being held onto by a long chain of items (mostly WPF objects) which is keeping the image in ram.

I've had a look over MSDN for all the objects that are being used and can't find anything that points out a problem with the way the code is running.

I've put together some sample code that closely follows the service (some bits reduced for bevity). This is called off a thread (set to STA). The only other differece is the service code uses MemoryStreams to load images sourced from a DB rather than the URIs I am using. The streams are disposed of:

```
    public static void TestThread()
    {
        const int rounds = 50;
        const int innerRounds = 50;
        var randomiser = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        // Simulating some live values
        const float scaling = 2.67F;
        const int pageWidth = 363;
        const int pageHeight = 516;
        const int dpi = 96;

        // To simulate the live system using multiple images
        // This is an list of images of different sizes etc
        var imageList = new List<ImageData>
        {
            new ImageData{Uri = new Uri(@"..."), Height = 2592},
            new ImageData{Uri = new Uri(@"..."), Height = 1339},
            new ImageData{Uri = new Uri(@"..."), Height = 386},
            new ImageData{Uri = new Uri(@"..."), Height = 968},
            new ImageData{Uri = new Uri(@"..."), Height = 1952},
            new ImageData{Uri = new Uri(@"..."), Height = 1024},
        };

        var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        for (var i = 0; i < rounds; ++i)
        {
            var canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.BeginInit();
            canvas.SnapsToDevicePixels = false;
            canvas.UseLayoutRounding = false;
            canvas.Width = pageWidth;
            canvas.Height = pageHeight;
            canvas.Background = Brushes.White;

            for (var j = 0; j < innerRounds; ++j)
            {
                var img = new Image {Stretch = Stretch.Fill};
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

                var imageNo = randomiser.Next(0, imageList.Count - 1);

                bitmapImage.UriSource = imageList[imageNo].Uri;
                int imageHeight = imageList[imageNo].Height;
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = (int) (imageHeight * scaling * 1.8);
                bitmapImage.EndInit();

                if (bitmapImage.CanFreeze)
                {
                    bitmapImage.Freeze();
                }

                var opacityMask = new ImageBrush();
                var opactityBitmap = new BitmapImage();
                opactityBitmap.BeginInit();
                opactityBitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

                imageNo = randomiser.Next(0, imageList.Count - 1);
                opactityBitmap.UriSource = imageList[imageNo].Uri;
                int opacityImageHeight = imageList[imageNo].Height; ;
                opactityBitmap.DecodePixelHeight = (int)(opacityImageHeight * scaling * 1.8);
                opactityBitmap.EndInit();

                if (opactityBitmap.CanFreeze)
                {
                    opactityBitmap.Freeze();
                }

                opacityMask.ImageSource = opactityBitmap;
                img.OpacityMask = opacityMask;

                img.Source = bitmapImage;
                img.Width = pageWidth * scaling;
                img.Height = pageHeight * scaling;
                Canvas.SetLeft(img, 0);
                Canvas.SetTop(img, 0);
                canvas.Children.Add(img);
                img.Opacity = 50F;
            }

            canvas.LayoutTransform = null;
            var size = new Size(Math.Max(canvas.Width, 5), Math.Max(canvas.Height, 5));
            canvas.Measure(size);
            canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));
            canvas.EndInit();

            var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(pageWidth, pageHeight, dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Default); //xxx

            renderTargetBitmap.Render(canvas);

            if (renderTargetBitmap.CanFreeze)
            {
                renderTargetBitmap.Freeze();
            }

            System.Drawing.Image imageData;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var image = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                image.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
                image.Save(ms);
                imageData = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            }


            var encoder = Encoder.Quality;
            var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, 100L);

            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
            var codecInfo = codecs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FormatID == ImageFormat.Png.Guid);

            Byte[] bitmapArray;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                imageData.Save(ms, codecInfo, encoderParams);
                bitmapArray = ms.GetBuffer();
            }

            var filepath = string.Format(@"C:\temp\{0}.png", i);
            imageData.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Png);

            var gcMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1024;
            Console.WriteLine("Proc mem = {0}KB, GC = {1}KB", (proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024), gcMemory);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
    }
```

I'm hoping it's something obvious I'm missing here. Thanks for all your help!